# Extract parameters of function using generics

Tags: typescript

What is the correct way of extracting parameters of a function using generics?

I'm trying to extract the parameters of this function:

```
interface Props<T> {
    data: T[];
    test: (x: T) => void
}

function fn<T>(props: Props<T>): void {
    return;
};
```

And pass them to a new function `fn2`. So that I would be the equivalent to`fn`.
Using the following does not work

```
type GetProps<T extends any> = T extends (props: infer U) => void ? U: never
type FnProps = GetProps<typeof fn>

function fn2<T>(props: FnProps<T>): void { // Type 'FnProps' is not generic
    return;
}
```

What is the correct way of writing `GetProps` here?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQAUYHsAOBnAHgBUA+VAb2FWtQBMEIEAuVIgbQF0BuKm6PCCwAUADxZEAlKgC8ZAG5YQtYAF9gwOAFcwSCCCxhUcMMRJCc2fC0y5CpCSwVKKvajCgRNMMDxU9gSAYCqO54MkZgQpQ0dAzMqGzkqCDQALYsAIwqHAA0rqj8gqiiUrKoIgB0KVCpqADUqBmqEuoQAJ44aADiHjb4xKhQItBgtGEIYG1k0qyDw1CjYeaWeCzgcLCoAKql8oq0qAD82yxgUHKwrR1oAGJgfWEzPRAPBO2dWHARJOpaOnoGCIAJlMy1sLDuDwcqCcB2iNHcnm8vnUgTAwVCQPCxiBUXy9EYLESyTSmWyeRihWEIl25SqaXqjVQAHpmSEECA8FAwgByEQ85JhT4Fa6oHnaADWYCwAHcwALmkA)

Comment: Have you looked at [Parameters<T>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly you could write your utility type as

```
type FnProps<T> = GetProps<typeof fn<T>>
```

and then

```
function fn2<T>(props: FnProps<T>): void {
    return;
}
```